# Does clip-path work on chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, clip-path

Does Chrome currently support using polygon on clip-path?

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 73%, 0 27%, 100% 16%, 100% 88%);
clip-path: polygon(0 73%, 0 27%, 100% 16%, 100% 88%);
```

I can get inset to work (see commented out code) but not polygon.

[Demo of clip-path using polygon](http://codepen.io/Widgeteria/pen/LErwLz)

Answer (score 0):

not sure why, but this code worked instead just fine.  first time using this, so probably had the parameters wrong.

```
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 25%, 100% 16%, 100% 89%, 0 64%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 25%, 100% 16%, 100% 89%, 0 64%);`
```